# Getting started with development for ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-web-adf

I'm currently working on upgrading a C# web service I wrote a couple of years ago built against ArcGIS Server to ArcGIS Server 10. The application in question does some basic spatial queries and exports several PDFs, so no addtional extensions are required however it cannot be hosted directly on the ArcGIS Server.

My problem is that I'm unsure of exactly which ESRI components I'll need and where they need to be installed.

Is what I've drawn up below reasonable?

### Developer PC

- Visual Studio 2010
- ArcEngine 10 Runtime
- ArcObjects 10 SDK

### Application Server

- ArcEngine 10 Runtime

### ArcGIS Server

- ArcGIS Server 10
- ArcGIS GIS Services

Comment: Not sure about ArcEngine 10 on the app server.  What will the app server be doing?

Comment: Hosting the web service in IIS, but it will essentially be remoting ArcGIS server via ArcObjects.

Comment: Based on what I've read this seems overly complex. Is this where Web ADF is supposed to come in?

Comment: I strongly recommend moving away from Web ADF ... it is being deprecated.  See notice [here](http://events.esri.com/uc/QandA/index.cfm?fuseaction=answer&conferenceId=AC1DD535-1422-2418-7F1722E62B9B416A&questionId=4323).

Comment: Thanks Kurk- while it is being depreciated I think this is the right tool for the job given we only really want to get the existing code we have working.

I suspect if we were to redevelop it in the future we'd do it completely differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up trying to do what I want through the direct code APIs and found that using the SOAP services for "Map Server" and "Geometry Server" expose more or less what I need and do not require licensing of additional ESRI components other than the ArcGIS server as I understand it.